# How to set mindate in hours in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery date picker . now i want set mindate as 62 hours but it is taking input only mindate : '3' ie.. means it takes 72 hours . i want only 62 hours . please help me to resolve this issue.thank you in advance
 i am attaching snap of code.

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 3, beforeShowDay: function(date){   var day = date.getDay();   return [day == 3 ,""];} });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the date for `now - 62hrs` and provide that as a paramter to the datepicker's `minDate` property

```
'minDate': new Date(((new Date).getTime() - 62 * 60 * 60 * 1000) )
```